# Is there any way to get specific data inside a ResultSet variable in java

Tags: java

I have a result set like;

```
ResultSet rs = connection.executeQuery("Select * From x");
```

Normally we are using 
`while(rs.next()) {}` for get each data.

But if i want to get this data only 1 time from database and use it every time with different select parameters how can i do this?
 i don't want to go to db every time. i want to select data from this resultset example `where id = 1;` or where `foreignkey=25;` inside the rs variable while my app running .

Comment: Why not simply `select * from x where id = 1` ? You don't want to access the db each time but what you seems to think is that you will search the data in the `ResultSet` on demand, but you need to close the connection at some point to be correct, the `ResultSet` will be closed on the same time. If you really don't want to ask the data for each condition. Simply persist the data in a `Collection`, but this cost memory... think about what is the best based on the amount of data, the request rate, ...

Comment: think about select data inside a for loop, select from db on each loop is makes app too slow. i want to select all data 1 time and use it in java application with less time

Comment: Create your query to select every data you need on one query. In your loop you build the query and the parameters. Outside the loop you instanciate the `PreparedStatement` and execute the query. All you have to do is iterate the `ResultSet` to get your data, it should be simply from there to used that `ResultSet` based on what you need.

Comment: @KadirKalkan then capture each row (and each column in that row) in any appropriate Java data structure. But remind that all data may not be stored in memory (DB can be very very huge).

Comment: For a simple explanation on the restriction you have. A `ResultSet` is ... a `Set`, all you can do is iterate the set from start to end and search for the field you need in each instances in that `Set`, a `ResultSet` require the connection to be opened because some driver don't recover the full result in memory, only the beginning and will fetch more if needed. Knowing that, you should understand that you can't do what you want with a `ResultSet`. (PS: you can ask for a `ResultSet` to be readable in both way)

Comment: i understand you clearly. Thank you for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to move your data to a Map and use the field (id or foreignkey) as the key and then do the lookups in that map(s).

Alternatively you add it to any type of collection and use streams and lambda expressions to get the right object.

Comment: as i thought, i just wonder can resultset methods do this itself. But thank you for answer

Comment: The result set holds database/jdbc resources so you should close it as soon as possible.